# How to display a black transparent view over a view in swiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to present a transparent view with black background over current view, so that we can still see the content of the current view. I have worked around the opacity modifier but it is not doing the job.

this is my code:

```
ZStack {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(.black)
            .ignoresSafeArea()
    VZScrollViewIfNeeded {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                // some code
    }
}
```

later I am presenting this view on click of other view:

````
buttonActionView()
     .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isPresenting, content: transparentView.init)```
````

Comment: Try putting the Rectangle View under the VZScrollView... View. Currently the Rectangle is behind the ScrollView. Then you can add an opacity which schould then work.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the order of your elements. Currently your Rectangle that should overlay the view is behind the ScrollView. Should look like this:

```
ZStack {
    VZScrollViewIfNeeded {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            // some code
    }

    Rectangle()
        .foregroundColor(Color.black.opacity(0.5))
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
}
```